# Looking for an ASCII image code formatter

Tags: code-formatting

I'm looking for a (probably old) website which had videos of a guy coding a generic program in C, and then formatting them manually to look like a movie or anime character.

Imagine things like these :

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/asivokon/harnocode/master/examples/jquery-01.js
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mame/quine-relay/master/QR.rb

Except not automatically generated but manually done.

If someone remembers the website where the videos are posted, I'd be grateful.

I'm also looking for a generic soft like this : https://github.com/asivokon/harnocode , except it works for most languages instead of only javascript.

If someone has a clue I'd love to hear it. Thanks !

Comment: It you want a program to do it, then ask at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and we may be able to help you  Best delete this question & Ask over there, before you get more downvotes here

Comment: Btw, the examples of GitHUb look slick!  Did you try other languages? I would love to do this at work, with C  :-)

Comment: @Mawg thanks for the recommendation, I didn't know this existed, I'll post there instead !

Comment: Be sure to read how to ask questions correctly for that site. We will do or best to help. Now, best delete this before someone else downvotes it. When the downvotes start, people here just think "me too" and downvote lots more

Comment: I couldn't care less about upvotes or downvotes. I usually ask my questions nicely, but this one is a little hard to explain, that's why it might look a little messy :)

Comment: ok. Poinst are only good for ego ;-) AND for offering a bounty, which can be very helpful if you are really stuck.  But, if you don't delete this question, then I will add a link to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39268/looking-for-an-ascii-image-code-formatter